# Bash error in perl script using HTML::Scrubber

Tags: perl, bash

```
USER:~/Directory>curl http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp | html.parser2.pl 
Can't locate HTML/Scrubber.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/local/lib64/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.10.0 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/5.10.0/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /usr/lib/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl .) at ./html.parser2.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./html.parser2.pl line 2.
```

What's happening here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What's happening is that perl can't find the `HTML::Scrubber` module, which is required somewhere in the `html.parser2.pl` script.

Usually, the fix is to install it with `cpan`

```
cpan HTML::Scrubber
```

or possibly one of

```
sudo cpan HTML::Scrubber

<perl> -MCPAN -e 'install "HTML::Scrubber"'
```

where `<perl>` is the full path to the version of `perl` in the `html.parser2.pl` script's shebang line.

This solution might not work for a number of reasons (`cpan` can fail building and installing the module, you have more than one version of `perl` on your system and you are installing the module in the "wrong" version, ...). If `cpan` doesn't fix your problem, ask another question here including all the relevant output from the `cpan` process and from your command line invocation of the script.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I now am getting this:

    cpan[2]> install HTML::Scrubber
    Reading '/home/user/.cpan/Metadata'
    Database was generated on Mon, 03 Jun 2013 02:17:02 GMT
    Running install for module 'HTML::Scrubber'
    Cannot create directory /root/.cpan/prefs

Comment: Can you run `cpan` as root?